# Tensorflow: *Save* the output Conv layer as a png image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have managed to get the output of a convolution layer show in tensorboard using the code below. My big challenge and where I am hoping you can help me is that I would like to be able to get that output saved in a png file (for example).

I have started doing it but cannot manage to get it to work 
using PIL or tensorflow encode. I have attached the code between ###### BEGIN END #####

Assuming that the output of my layer is a tensor of shape (64, 16, 16, 1) Is there a very simple way extract and save the first element of that tensor, i.e. (64, 64, 1), as a png/jpeg image using PIL/numpy or TF ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help.
N.

```
def _view_layer(name, layer, w, h, d, training=True):
    L = tf.slice(layer, (0, 0, 0, 0), (1, -1, -1, -1), name='slice_first_input')
    L = tf.reshape(L, (w, h, d))

    L = tf.transpose(L, (2, 0, 1))
    # Bring into shape expected by image_summary
    L = tf.reshape(L, (-1, w, h, 1))

    ###### BEGIN save as image ### not working #################################
    if(training == False):
        print(L.get_shape())
        img_f = tf.image.resize_images(L, 64, 64, method=2)  # 224
        img_int = tf.cast(img_f, tf.uint8)
        print(img_int.get_shape())
        slice_im_2d = img_int[0, 2:66, 2:66, :] #<=Not sure how to get (64, 64, 1)
        print(slice_im_2d.get_shape())

        # Trying with PIL
        # im = Image.fromarray(np.array(slice_im_2d).astype(np.uint8))
        # im.save( datetime.now() + ".png")

        # png_bin = tf.image.encode_png(slice_im_2d)

        # Trying with TensorFlow
        # with tf.Session().as_default():
        #     format_str = ('%s.png')
        #     fr = format_str % datetime.now()
        #     f = open(fr, "wb+")
        #     f.write(png_bin.eval())
        #     f.close()
    ###### END save as image ### not working #################################

    # show in Tensorboard summary
    tf.image_summary(name, V)
```

Comment: You have to get the numpy array value of your image using `sess.run()` first before manipulating it in python

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Merci for your prompt answer. In thge method above I am now doing `slice = tf.slice(img_f , [0,0,0,0], [1,64,64,1])` which gives me a tensor of shape (1, 64, 64, 1) the issue is now that when I go with: 

` s = sess.run([slice]) format_str = ('%s.png') fr = format_str % datetime.now() im = Image.fromarray(np.array(s).astype(np.uint8) im.save(fr)`

I get : TypeError: Cannot handle this data type I am thinking it is because it is not an RGB image.

Comment: Try to reshape to `[64, 64]` or `[64, 64, 1]`

Comment: Additional debug information: `KeyError: ((1,1,64,1), '|u1')`

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Using `slice_im_2d = img_f[0,0:64,0:64, 0]` all the output images are fully black and do not look like the ones in `tf.image_summary(name, L)` at all. The later images seem to contain rich features I am hoping to be able to save in a png file.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values of `img_f`? You can get these with `sess.run(tf.reduce_max(img_f))`. They should be `0` and `255` to visualize well.